# Graph Theory - Length of Cycle UnDirected Graph - Adjacency Matrix

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Study Review Question for comprehensive Exam for algorithms part.

> Let G be an undirected Graph with n vertices that contains exactly one cycle and isolated vertices (i.e. no leaves). That means the degree of a vertex is 0 (isolated) if it is not in the cycle and 2 if it is part of the cycle. Assume that the graph is reresented by an adjacency matrix. **Describe** an efficeint algorithm that finds the length of the cycle.

I am looking for assistance on verifying my understanding, checking if it is correct and if the analysis is also correct.

My Answer (pseudo pythonic)

```
visited = [] // this will be list of u,v pairs belonging to cycle

for each u,v in G[][]:
    if G[u][v] == 1:      // is an edge
        if G[u][v] in visited : // 
            return len(visited) // return the length of the cycle, since weve hit begining of cycle
        else :
             visited.add((u,v))
```

English Based understanding

- We know a cycle must exist, be definition of the question, the case wherein no cycle found need not be accounted for
- For each pair of vertices, check if it is an edge
- if it is an edge, check if weve been there before. If we have, we've found the cycle, and return the size of all visited edges. (size of cycle)
- If it is not a visited edge, add it to the visited list, and continue until we find the source edge (grow the cycle by 1 until we hit source)

My analysis for it I think may be off. Since we visit each (u,v) pair at least once, AND then check if it is an edge, as well as 2 comparisons per edge. I think it comes to O(|v|^2 + 2 |E|)

- # of vertices, squared (since we visit every pair in a matrix), + 2 comparisons per edge.

Can someone please advise on efficiency and correctness? Also maybe provide more english based understanding if there is a logical leap I may have made, without acknowledge the proof of logic?

Thanks for reading and thanks in advance for assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the conditions in the question (that is, the only edges in the graph are part of the cycle), the length of the cycle is the number edges in the graph, which is half the number of 1s in the adjacency matrix (each edge (i, j) appears twice in the adjacency matrix: A[i,j]=1 and A[j,i]=1).

The obvious algorithm therefore is to just sum the entries of the adjacency matrix and divide by 2. This is O(V^2) if there's V vertices.

One thing that looks like it might help is, once you've found the first 1 in the adjacency matrix, follow edges until you've got back to the start:

```
Find i, j such that A[i, j]=1.
start = i
cycle_length = 1
repeat
    find k != i with A[j, k] = 1
    i, j = j, k
    cycle_length++
until i = start
```

After this process terminates, `cycle_length` is the length of the cycle. This is still worst-case O(V^2) though, although if you can find a single vertex on the cycle quickly, it's O(V*C) where C is the length of the cycle.

The code in your question doesn't work. You're iterating over (u, v) as indexes in the matrix, and it's impossible to find the same (u, v) twice.

Comment: `G[v][u] in visited `Would work?, since we know thje return edge will be the reverse?  But definately summation is simplest way! thanks!

Comment: @Busturdust I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question in your comment.

Comment: IF we searched the visited array, for the reverse of the current edge, would that work? We know that if (u,v) is in visted, and if we are on (v,u) it must be a cycle

Comment: @Busturdust you could try and implement it and test it by generating random graphs with a cycle of known length and see if it returns the right results. Or try the techniques in http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

Since theres exactly one cycle, a vertex is part of the cycle, if he is connected to atleast one other vertex. Since the graph is undirected, the following rule can be used:
`if a edge between v1 and v2 exists, the edge aswell exists between v2 and v1` or in other words: the algorithm only needs to scan the part of the matrix where `v1 < v2` is given, which reduces the number of matrixelements read even in worstcase by more than 50%. And since were searching a cylce, we can simply save every node we have visited before the previous node to ensure we don't visit it again and end, if we end up with the current node being equal to the starting node.

```
//search for any node that is in the cycle
int firstNode = -1

for int i in 1 , len(graph)
    boolean notIsolated = false

    for int j in 0 , i - 1
         if graph[i][j] == 1
             notIsolated = true
             break

    if notIsolated
         firstNode = i
         break

int node_c = firstNode
int node_p = -1
int count = 0

do
    //search the neighbour that isn't the previous node with above given
    //optimizations
    int n
    for n in 0 , node_c - 1
        if graph[node_c][n] == 1 AND n != node_p
             break

    //update the nodevars for the next step
    node_p = node_c
    node_c = n        

    ++count
while node_c != firstNode //continue until the algorithm reaches the startnode
```

Apart from that, there won't be much to be optimized (at least i don't know any way to further optimize runtime).

Comment: s this analysis of my above code correct? and how do I properly analyze this? is it just O(|E|) ? Since you've eliminated the need to check undirected edges twice (duh I shouldve seen that)

Comment: i'm absolutely horrible at analyzing algorithms (no idea why, but i'm far better at coming up with algorithms than analyzing them), so you should rather ask someone else about this, but i think your algorithm has O(v^2) and mine has O(v * e / 2). And i noticed a bug in your algorithm: if (u , v) is visited,  (v , u) can still be visited and will be counted as separate edge.

Comment: This algorithm is also O(v^2), as indeed any solution has to be given the graph's represented as an adjacency matrix.

Comment: @Busturdust why did you accept the other answer? that's just a cooked down - and late - copy of my pseudocode with several optimizations missing

Comment: @Paul It was easier to understand, the inclusion of the summation principle, and the realization that my code will never find the cycle, since we iterate of U,V and will never check the same U,V twice. My pseudo code would **not** be correct, is the most important point I could ask for